# How to select tree from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Have data like this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (name1 varchar(5),name2 varchar(5),name3 varchar(5))
INSERT INTO @tbl(name1,name2,name3) 
values ('P1','A1','AA1'),('P1','B1','AA2'),('P1','C1','AA3'),('P1','A1','AA4')
```

Input table is:

```
name1   name2   name3
P1        A1    AA1
P1        B1    AA2
P1        C1    AA3
P1        A1    AA4
```

I want to select from this a little bit strange tree, result must be like this:

```
col1    col2
 P1      A1
 A1      AA1
 A1      AA4
 P1      B1
 B1      AA2
 P1      C1
 C1      AA4
```

Example for first rows `'P1','A1','AA1'` `P1` is root for `A1`, `A1` is root for `AA1` but also `A1` is root for `AA4` in `'P1','A1','AA4'`.That's why output must be like:

```
P1      A1
A1      AA1
A1      AA4
```

Sqlfiddle : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/87eb3/1

Comment: What defines the output rows?

Comment: @Richard I edited question

Comment: Adding the sample data is tabular format will make the question much more readable and help us figure out a possible solution.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos edited

Comment: The solution seems to be very straightforward: `SELECT name1 AS col1, name2 AS col2 FROM @tbl UNION  SELECT name2 AS col1, name3 AS col2 FROM @tbl`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos what about ordering ? Result must be in that order which I have in question

Comment: Your input data doesn't have any order (since there is no column that determines order). How do you expect your output to be ordered?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos For example take one name1,name2 and write down all name2 childs (name3)

Comment: That's the loosest definition of the term 'tree' I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is, is what your looking for:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM 
(
    SELECT name2 AS child, 0 AS type, name1 AS col1, name2 AS col2
    FROM @tbl

    UNION 

    SELECT name2 AS child, 1 AS type, name2 AS col1, name3 AS col2
    FROM @tbl
) AS t
ORDER BY child DESC, type, col1, col2
```

Sample output:

```
col1    col2
------------
P1      C1
C1      AA3
P1      B1
B1      AA2
P1      A1
A1      AA1
A1      AA4
```

Comment: Yes ! Thank you !